# Does the system use the space on the hard disk which has never been written on, before over-writing the deleted files?

Tags: hard-disk, disk

Suppose the total capacity of the hard disk is 1 TB but the user always uses about 500 GB. While allocating new space, does the system give preference to the never used space or overwrites deleted files on the disk?
If it is the first case, can deleted files still remain on the hard disk for years?

Comment: That depends on the type of filesystem in use.

Comment: Deleted files can indeed remain on the hard disk for years, as to how the file system allocates space for new files I' not sure, but it's possible that it also depends on the type of storage. With a spinning HDD it will probably be advantageous to just use the free space nearest to the current position of the read/write head, irrespective of whether it's a never used block or if it belonged to a deleted file.